add items from one List View to another List View using pywinauto
I am trying to automate a desktop application where I have to drag items from a list view and drop it into another list view.
How can I do it??
Source List View:
avl_fields = app.TestWindow.child_window(title ="Available Fields" , auto_id="#123#", control_type= "List").wrapper_object()
Target List View:
values = app.TestWindow.child_window(title ="Values" , auto_id="#345#", control_type= "List").wrapper_object()
Selecting source items code :
for item in avl_fields.items():
item.click_input(button='left', pressed='control')
I want to drag and drop list view items to another list view items.
No idea how to do this.

There is a unit test for TreeView: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_uiawrapper.py#L1988 Maybe it will help to do the same for ListView.
